# c++ is there any possibility that `map.end()` can change during the life time of a `std::map`

Tags: c++, dictionary

just wondering if I have a map declared like this,

```
map<int, int> my_map;
```

and assign `end()` iterator to a variable, and never change,

```
auto end_it = my_map.end()
```

Then later I will change `my_map` by having many erase and insert of `my_map`,
will the below always stays true during the life time of `my_map`?

```
end_it == my_map.end()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: Also see [Is end() required to be constant in an STL map/set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1432216/10147399)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[std::map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) guarantees:

> No iterators or references are invalidated.

[std::map::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) guarantees:

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

Therefore the end iterator should stay valid. If you use any other operation, you should check whether it might invalidate the iterators.

Answer (score 2):

[std::map::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/swap) **does invalidate** the `end()` iterator:

> All iterators and references remain valid. The end() iterator is invalidated.